# В чем причина пустого пространства между блоками

Tags: html, css

На сайте есть пустое пространство, могу устранить его отрицательным маржин для футера, но все же, в чем причина то?!
Причина найдена, може кому поможет в будущем. Часто причинй есть неучтенный margin где то в верстке. В моем случае я проверил все, ничего подобного не было. Причину нашел посредством инструмента "Edit as HTML" в браузере Google Chrome. Я нашел какой то символ, который в обычном коде не отображался. Увидеть его удалось только через данный инструмент http://pastenow.ru/d154f781f9024c23940a49d7ef074da8
В шаблоне он отображался так http://pastenow.ru/0a4f2c0c8df2b01a192085247a09404d в конце. 
Для тех, кто будет в будущем искать ответ на подобный вопрос: важно помнить что проблема обязательно связана с чем то, это точно не мистика)

Comment: у contacts установлен margin в 30 пикселей.

Comment: нет, ставлю 0  и ничего...

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин нет, если убрать этот маргин, то ничего не изменится

Comment: `.container:after {content: " ";}` — в этом причина (вроде бы)

Comment: [«Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263)

Comment: у меня убирается. Просто зависит чего именно вы хотите убрать, это можно в скрине показать, что лишнее. Еще можно посмотреть padding у contacts-email.

Comment: Нет, не в афтер. Это стандартная бутстраповская тема. Согласен, неправильно давать ссылку... Но и проблему нельзя как то конкретизировать, увы. Стандартный ответ в таких случаях где то есть неучтенный маржин, но я его тут не вижу... Все пересмотрел. Разве что весь код сайта сюда выкладывать

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин конкретно нужно убрать прозрачную полоску вверху футера, не под футером пространство

Comment: @Vova_Smail, скрипты уберите между контентом и футером и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Необходимо выложить ту часть кода где воспроизводится проблема.

Comment: @Vova_Smail, хотя скорее не скрипты, а `<div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>` `<div class="clearfix"></div>`.

Comment: @Visman Убрал все вклчительно с коментариями с помощью "edit as HTML" в гугл хром, не помогло

Comment: убрать можна просто добавив до `footer{margin-top: -20px;}`. только вот почему такое твориться. немогу найти

Comment: @klifort Да, я это знаю. Здесь уже вопрос принципа узнать истину)